# show databsaes casues FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am completely new to hadoop and have been working on installing hive using this tutorial 
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoo/BigData_hadoop_Hive_Install_On_Ubuntu_16_04.php
although I have a 14.04 system. 
In the last step after hive is installed and I am using HQL especially the ones dealing with output such as:

```
hive > show tables; or `hive > show databases;`
```

Instead of getting OK, I get the output as

```
FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./%20/tmp/hduser%20/89ac0809-64cc-4200-82c7-1d52f1b6a997/hive_2017-11-07_01-31-29_360_4783575963309532883-1
```

All the other commands are working fine however the above command isn't working. I checked on line and made few changes to my hive-site.xml file however nothing changed
The important properties of file:

**hive-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive-${user.name}</value>
    <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/&lt;username&gt; is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.</description>
  </property>

 <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
  <!-- <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name}</value>-->
<value> /tmp/${user.name} </value>
    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
 <!-- <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
-->
<value>/home/hduser/hive/tmp/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
    <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
  </property>

 <property>
    <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
    <value>733</value>
    <description>The permission for the user specific scratch directories that get created.</description>
  </property>
```

I tried working on many things however I am yet stuck here only. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Are you using HDFS, or just local filesystem?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I am using HDFS as well

Comment: Okay, well, `file:./%20/tmp/hduser%20/` is something wrong with a config file. You have a space in `file://` and the user account `"hduser "`, as shown by the `%20`